# How to record information about declined email invites sent from a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, email, backend

I am working on a rails app which sends out email invites to a bunch of users. In almost every situation, all the recipients do not accept the email invite. So is it possible to figure out the recipients from the recipients list who declined the email invite ?

If not possible in rails, is this at all possible to figure out ?

-Thanks,
Vinit

Comment: How are you sending invitations? manually or through some gems eg. devise invitable? You could check a db column named :accepted_at to check declined(nil) invitations

Comment: I was sending the email invites through AWS SES but I am open to using gems. Thanks for the recommendation. I will take a look at `devise invitable` gem